No module named 'torch._six' to import queue
I'm trying to apply a RCAN model from the github https://github.com/sanghyun-son/EDSR-PyTorch . I am using pytorch 2.0.1. I am getting the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._six'

when trying to import:
from torch._six import queue

Any suggestions on how to resolve this without going down to torch 1.0 ?
I have tried the following alternatives:
from six import queue
from multiprocessing import Queue as queue
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue as queue

all of which raise new errors. I am not sure what function I could even use to replace queue if it is deprecated since I am not very familiar with pytorch or the model code.

Relevant: Remove dependency on six and future

I think maybe if I were you, I would consider updating Python to 3.8 or higher and see if that works.

Quick solution:
Go to respective utils.py file and remove the following lines:
from taming.data.helper_types import Annotation
from torch._six import string_classes
from torch.utils.data._utils.collate import np_str_obj_array_pattern, default_collate_err_msg_format
from tqdm import tqdm

I hope this resolves your issue.
